# is a Function which using useeffect which returns only response of api can be callable in method of another component?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

i just read up the documentation of react useEffect , and they put this example

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus(props) {
const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
function handleStatusChange(status) {
  setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
}

ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
// Specify how to clean up after this effect:
return function cleanup() {
  ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
};
});

if (isOnline === null) {
  return 'Loading...';
}
 return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

According to this example **can i use this in my any method of some other component** ? if yes then how ? should i have to make that method async .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll always use async functions to make API calls, but in this case, since the API call is inside the useEffect and the request is made after the page render, there's no problem. Async method makes a function load after the others and useEffect has that effect already.

Comment: can you please put up an example